# Non-breaking space between lines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml, html-entities

How could I join two HAML lines with a non-breaking space (& nbsp;) and no actual space, e.g.:

```
= 'foo'
%a(href='http://example.com') bar
```

I tried using the `succeed` helper, but a space is still generated between them. I want to remove the space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How did you use [succeed](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Haml/Helpers.html#succeed-instance_method)? Where did the space end up?

Did you combine it with the [whitespace removal chars (`"<"` and `">"`)](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#whitespace_removal__and_) or try them on their own?

```
= succeed '&nbsp;'.html_safe do
  = 'foo'
%a(href='http://example.com')> bar
```

This produces:

```
foo&nbsp;<a href='http://example.com'>bar</a>
```

Is that literally what you want? It *is* "two lines joined by a non-breaking space with no actual space."

*(IMO, [HAML is meh for inline content](http://chriseppstein.github.com/blog/2010/02/08/haml-sucks-for-content/), and just no fun. Nice for layout.)*

Comment: Thanks, sorry it wasn't clear, I tried providing an example of the output initially but it was demolished by the SO formatter.

Comment: This answer is almost what I'm looking for, the only issue is the nbsp is escaped, ie it converts the & to &amp;. I can't see how to avoid that, I've tried != on both of the top 2 lines, but to no avail.

(And I agree, HAML isn't great for content...but sometimes a necessary evil.)

Comment: @mahemoff Use `raw` or `html_safe`--I was doing it outside of Rails.

Comment: [Whitespace removal chars url (`<` and `>`)](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#whitespace_removal__and_)

Comment: @e.sambo What? I mentioned them.